# What does it mean to say it "converges geometrically"

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, approximation, geometric-series

I've been reading up on some algorithms and I've come across the statement "it converges geometrically" but what does this mean? How does it differ from saying "it converges"? Is there some "rate" behind the word "geometric" in this sense? Since I'm posting the question, is there other "forms of convergence" I should be aware of....algebraic?

Comment: Perhaps there is a definition earlier?  My guess.  $x_n$ converges geometrically to $x$ if there is $C>0$ and $r<1$ such that $d(x_n-x) < Cr^n$ for all $n$.

Comment: It tends to mean that it converges at the rate that $r^n \to 0$ with $|r|<1$